# SQL Server : select distinct dates plus condition and count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to select and count the distinct days from one column and also exclude those that have a certain value in other column.

The table structure is like this;

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|           DAY           |          CHECK          |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2018-07-18 00:00:00.000 | 2018-07-18 12:46:35.000 |
| 2018-07-19 00:00:00.000 | 2018-07-19 15:58:14.000 |
| 2018-07-20 00:00:00.000 | 2018-07-20 15:52:57.000 |
| 2018-07-21 00:00:00.000 | 2018-07-21 00:00:00.000 |
| 2018-07-23 00:00:00.000 | 2018-07-23 08:54:49.000 |
| 2018-07-23 00:00:00.000 | 2018-07-23 12:52:41.000 |
| 2018-07-26 00:00:00.000 | 2018-07-26 08:55:34.000 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

So the expected result would be a count of the different days in column DAY and in that count exclude all, the day from the CHECK column that have this time 00:00:00.000.

In this case the result of the count would be 5 days

I managed to count the days but haven't figured out the condition part of the check column

```
COUNT(DISTINCT DAY) AS 'TotalDays',
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `GROUP BY` and then implement the check with an `HAVING` clause:

```
declare @tmp table ([day] datetime , [check] datetime)

insert into @tmp values
 ('2018-07-18 00:00:00.000','2018-07-18 12:46:35.000')
,('2018-07-19 00:00:00.000','2018-07-19 15:58:14.000')
,('2018-07-20 00:00:00.000','2018-07-20 15:52:57.000')
,('2018-07-21 00:00:00.000','2018-07-21 00:00:00.000')
,('2018-07-23 00:00:00.000','2018-07-23 08:54:49.000')
,('2018-07-23 00:00:00.000','2018-07-23 12:52:41.000')
,('2018-07-26 00:00:00.000','2018-07-26 08:55:34.000')

select [DAY] 
from @tmp
group by [DAY]
having min(cast ([check] as time)) <> '00:00:00.0000000'
```

Result:

[image]

Since you want a count you can wrap the statement with another select:

```
select count(*) as TotalDays
from
(
    select [DAY] 
    from @tmp
    group by [DAY]
    having min(cast ([check] as time)) <> '00:00:00.0000000'
) T
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [DAY]) AS 'TotalDays'
FROM tbl
WHERE [CHECK] <> DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, [CHECK]), 0);
```

Looking at your sample data, maybe a WHERE clause of `WHERE [CHECK] <> [DAY]` is sufficient.